# How would you simplify this?

Tags: python

Ok i have this monstrosity, how would you simplify it? Using loop?

```
if season in range(1, 5):
        if episode_num == 1:
            if season == 1:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s1_path + episodes_s1[0]])
            elif season == 2:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s2_path + episodes_s2[0]])
            elif season == 3:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s3_path + episodes_s3[0]])
            else:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s4_path + episodes_s4[0]])
        elif episode_num == 2:
            if season == 1:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s1_path + episodes_s1[episode_num-1]])
            elif season == 2:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s2_path + episodes_s2[episode_num-1]])
            elif season == 3:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s3_path + episodes_s3[episode_num-1]])
            else:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s4_path + episodes_s4[episode_num-1]])
        elif episode_num == 3:
            if season == 1:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s1_path + episodes_s1[episode_num-1]])
            elif season == 2:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s2_path + episodes_s2[episode_num-1]])
            elif season == 3:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s3_path + episodes_s3[episode_num-1]])
            else:
                subprocess.Popen([player_path, s4_path + episodes_s4[episode_num-1]])
        elif episode_num == 4: ...
```

*season* and *episode_num* are **ints** acquired by input()

*player_path* and *sX_path* are **strings**;

*episodes_sX* is **list**

Comment: This depends on some of the guarantees that can be made about the data- are there always only 4 seasons? What is the maximum number of episodes?

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit lost with the goal of this code. could you walk me through? I mean, I understand the code but can you describe a high level approach?

Comment: First, I would put all paths in dictionaries, like path_dict = {1: s1_path, 2: s2_path, ....}, this way you can eliminate the inside ifs.

Comment: @PhilipAdler yes always 4 seasons, maximum number op episodes is 22. serkef, can you show me an example where you eliminated inside ifs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. I tried to keep readability and simplicity in the definition of data structures. The main idea is to link `sX_path` with `episodes_sX` (in a list in my case):

```
d = ['unused',
     [s1_path,episodes_s1],
     [s2_path,episodes_s2],
     [s3_path,episodes_s3],
     [s4_path,episodes_s4]]

if (season in range(1,5)) and (episodeNum in range(1,len(d[season][1])+1)):
    subprocess.Popen([player_path, d[season][0] + d[season][1][episodeNum-1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to change your data structure.

For example

```
program = {"s_paths":["1","2","3"],"s_episodes":[["1","2"],["1","2"]]}
```

Now you can access them without all the IF statments

```
program['s_paths'][season - 1]
program['s_episodes'][season - 1][episode_num - 1]
```

So simply you can just return

```
subprocess.Popen([player_path, program['s_paths'][season - 1] + program['s_episodes'][season - 1][episode_num - 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
season_path = "s{}_path".format(season)
episodes = [
    episodes_s1,
    episodes_s2,
    episodes_s3,
    episodes_s4,
]

subprocess.Popen([player_path, s1_path + episodes[season - 1][episode_num - 1]])
```

Comment: hmm season_path is a string like literal "s1_path", probably there is already a path variable like "C:/files/season_1"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is an initial thought, without very deep understanding from my side.
Your code can be transformed to this (more or less):

```
player_path = 'C:/myplayer'
s1_path = 'C:/files/s1'
s2_path = 'C:/files/s2'
s3_path = 'C:/files/s3'
s4_path = 'C:/files/s4'
episodes_s1 = ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03']
episodes_s2 = ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03']
episodes_s3 = ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03']
episodes_s4 = ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03']

season_paths = {k:v for k, v in enumerate([s1_path, s2_path, s3_path, s4_path], 1)}
# season_paths = {1: 'C:/files/s1', 2: 'C:/files/s2', 3: 'C:/files/s3', 4: 'C:/files/s4'}

season_episodes = {k:v for k, v in enumerate([episodes_s1, episodes_s2, episodes_s3, episodes_s4, ...], 1)}
# season_episodes = {1: ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03'],
#                    2: ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03'],
#                    3: ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03'],
#                    4: ['ep01', 'ep02', 'ep03']}

season = 1
episode_num = 2
print([player_path, season_paths[season], season_episodes[season][episode_num - 1])
# ['C:/myplayer', 'C:/files/s1', 'ep02']

if season in range(1,5):
    subprocess.Popen([player_path, season_paths[season], season_episodes[season][episode_num - 1]])
```

edit: now I understand a bit more your quest here. User provides season and episode, you have already lists with paths and episodes and you want to start player accordingly.

I would remove the `if season in range`, call the subprocess directly and check for exceptions like this:

```
try:
    subprocess.Popen([player_path, season_paths[season], season_episodes[season][episode_num - 1]])
except IOError, ...:
    print("Could not start player {} with file {}".format(player_path,season_paths[season]))
```

Comment: python 2.7 throws `season_paths = {k, v for k, v in enumerate([s1_path, s2_path, s3_path, s4_path, ...], 1)}
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: what is the error? I run the exact code without issues. I have added vars initialization to help you with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you this way :

```
import os

seasons = [
        (s1_path, episodes_s1),
        (s2_path, episodes_s2),
        (s3_path, episodes_s3)
    ]

if season in range(0, len(seasons)):
    if episode_num in range(0, len(seasons[season][1])): # seasons[season][1]) is the seasons episodes

        # Create path via os.path.join, better way
        episode_path = os.path.join(seasons[season][0], seasons[season][1][episode_num - 1])
        subprocess.Popen([player_path, episode_path])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as well an array of array of objects/structure containing you data.
And acces it like Myserie[1][3].path